# I don't want X making Y do Z

Tags: relative-pronouns, relative-clauses, causatives

I'd be very happy if there is someone who will help me solve these **causative with relative** constructs:

> 1) I don't want dwarves get (got?) killed by elves

means that: *elves make somebody kill dwarves and I don't want it*. If it doesn't, how can I build this sentence?

> 2) I don't want dwarves (to be?) killed by elves

means that: *there is dwarves which is killed directly by elves and I don't want it*. If it doesn't how can I build this sentence?

> 3a) I don't want elves making hobbits kill dwarves
>   3b) I don't want elves to make hobbits kill dwarves
>   3c) I don't want elves killing dwarves
>   3d) I don't want elves to kill dwarves

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) I don't want dwarves get (got?) killed by elves

should be

> I don't want dwarves getting killed by elves

This still seems like a direct (not indirect) action by the elves. If it should be indirect, it could be changed as follows:

> I don't want dwarves getting killed because of the elves' actions/orders
>   I don't want dwarves getting killed because of something the elves ordered
>   I don't want dwarves getting killed because of the elves...
>   I don't want the elves forcing anybody to kill the dwarves
>   even more choices...

Next,

> 2) I don't want dwarves (to be?) killed by elves

This depends on whether it's a command or a statement. If it's a statement:

> I don't want the dwarves to be killed by the elves

if it's a command:

> I don't want any dwarves killed by elves

Next, 3a and 3c are both correct grammatically:

> 3a) I don't want elves making hobbits kill dwarves
>   3c) I don't want elves killing dwarves

3c is direct action. 
3a is indirection action, since the hobbits are responsible.

Comment: What about 3b and 3d sir?

Comment: @NevzatDoğukanErbek Could you clarify if these phrases are meant to be plain statements of fact, or if they are more like commandments/orders?  The answer would be different.

Comment: They are statements. Just like I don't want my friends to be died because I like them.

Comment: @NevzatDoğukanErbek , 3d is ok. 3b doesn't sound exactly right for some reason. Adding articles is a way to fix 3b: "I don't want the elves to make the hobbits kill the dwarves".

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one more question about my sentence above. Should it be "I don't my friends to be died" or "I don't my friends to die" or "I don't my friends to be dead". Sorry for bothering you but some verbs are complicated..

Comment: @NevzatDoğukanErbek "to be died", no. "to die", yes, it's grammatically correct and the right choice here.  "to be dead", is more complicated to explain. It's a slightly unusual wording for this case, however not wrong...  The quick answer is, say "to die".